# How to play with an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm facing the issue when arranging one array in PHP. Please help me out.
Below is the brief code which i'm using.

```
$array1 = array("image_1.png","image_2.png","image_3.png","image_4.png","image_5.png","image_6.png","image_7.png"); 

$array2 = $record['image_4.png'];
```

Now see what i want to be in final array;

```
$arrFinal = array("image_6.png","image_4.png","image_2.png","image_3.png");
```

**Here is the funda for above result :** *i want the array in result where it have only 4 random values of array1. but it must have value of array2 in it and all values of array must be unique.*

Please help me out from this..it will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: @Herbert: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/funda

Comment: i have tried all the main function for array: array_rand(),array_unique() and array_merge() but couldn't find a real way..Thx

Comment: Is $array2 actually supposed to be an array? To me it looks like it is the value of some other array called $record at index 'image_4.png'...?

Comment: Thankx all of you for your efforts & responses..I done it by your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

You'd need to remove array2 from array1 first:

```
$newarray = array_diff($array1,$array2);
```

So you'd pick 3 random ones:

```
$temparray = array_rand(array_flip($newarray),3); // note array_flip will allow this to return the value, not the keys.
```

Then add on the array2:

```
$arrFinal = array_merge($temparray,$array2);
```

Then if you want them in a random order just use

```
shuffle($arrFinal);
```

Comment: what about uniqueness of an final array ?? i dont think its create unique array..

Comment: the final array will hold unique elements as long as the arrays you start with ($array1, $array2) only hold unique elements.

Comment: both are having unique elements but what if after merging it. ? array1 contain element of array2 also..so

Comment: It's not going to. The point in removing the item in array2 from array1 in the first place is so your not pulling that item out when you get random items from the array. You then get 3 random items out, append the item you want to force to be in there, then merge them...I really don't see how I can explain that in a different way...

Answer (score 5):

The basic algorithm would go like this (described a little more general than the question states, for two arbitrary arrays array1 and array2, and an arbitrary desired length for the resulting array):

1. Build an array of the elements which are in array1 but not in array2
2. If the element count of the remaining list and array2 combined smaller than desired length:

   -> Then we can't build the result, there's just not enough elements
3. Build an array of as many random elements from diff as are missing from array2 to reach desired length
4. As result, merge array2 with the random array created in the previous step.

In PHP, that would go something like this (assuming `$array2` is really an array, that's not 100% clear from the code shown in the question):

```
// if you're not sure that $array1 and $array 2 only hold unique values, do this:
$array1 = array_unique($array1);
$array2 = array_unique($array2);

// actual algorithm:
$DesiredLength = 4;  // can be passed in as parameter or defined as constant
$diffarray = array_diff($array1, $array2);
if (count($diffarray) + count($array2) < $DesiredLength) {
    echo "Impossible, not enough unique elements!";
}
$randarray = array_rand(array_flip($diffarray), $DesiredLength - count($array2));
$arrFinal = array_merge($randarray, $array2);
```

with a little inspiration from other answers (`array_rand`, `array_merge`). For explanation why the `array_flip` is done, see the [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) documentation - `array_rand` would actually return the keys; but since your values are strings and unique, we can simply use the values as keys and with that trick get random values directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
$requried = 4;
$arrFinal = $array2;

$array1_2 = array_diff($array1, $array2);

shuffle($array1_2);
$i= count($arrFinal);
$j=0;

while($i<$required){
  $arrFinal[] = $array1_2[$j];
    $i++;
    $j++;
    if($j==count($array1_2)) break;
}
```

I have no doubt that this can be tidied up, but hopefully it is of use as a nudge in the right direction.

For reference, the php manual pages: [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), [array_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php), [shuffle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php), [count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

Answer (score 1):

First you should remove the element that you're going to enter to the result manually from the source array. Then you can use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to randomize the array and then select any number of elements from the shuffled array...

Comment: You probably want to run array_unique() on the first array to make sure there are no duplicates.